# I build static qt from source. How to set the path so that it acts as default?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04, qt5.5

Followed this procedure:
http://omg-it.works/how-to-build-a-version-of-qt-that-can-be-statically-linked/

So, qt is here:

```
    $ cd /opt/Qt5.5/5.5-static/
    $ ls
    bin  doc  examples  imports  include  lib  mkspecs  phrasebooks  plugins  qml  translations
    $ 
    $ which qmake
      /usr/bin/qmake
    $ 
    $ cd Desktop/yyyy/
    $ qmake yyyy.pro  
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
    $
```

How to set the path to this statically built qt? I don't have any qtcreator.

Comment: Calling `qmake` will try to call `/usr/bin/qmake`, as described by the `which` you issued. Try calling it directly? `$ /opt/Qt5.5/5.5-static/bin/qmake yyyy.pro`

Comment: thanks, what is the way to set it to default? @polarysekt

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116254/how-do-i-change-which-version-of-qt-is-used-for-qmake#233982 -- I don't know how system-specific the process might be, but looking at `/usr/bin/qmake`, I saw it pointed to `qtchooser`. Then a `man qtchooser` gave some interesting information. Of note were the environment variables.

Comment: I apologize I didn't fully read the question at my first comment.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Qt. All you want is an alias.